# How can I set up a rule in Outlook based on time of day a message was received?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I created an InfoPath form that the user submits from a Sharepoint site, and is received as an email.

I have the current rules set up to auto-reply with a message when the form is received.

However I need to be able to have two auto-replies. One message that replies if the submission is prior to 3PM (EST), and the other for anything after.

Answer (score 5):

If I consult properties of a mail in my Outlook mailbox, the firsts lines of the header is something like this

```
Received: from TRUC.COM (A.B.C.D) by
 TRUC2.COM (E.F.G.H) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id I.J.K.L; Tue, 25 Mar 2014 12:06:35 +0100
```

So, I've just tested two rules, 
one with the condition :

**header contains ' 00:' OR ' 01:' OR ' 02:' ... OR ' 12:'**

the other with the condition

**header contains ' 13:' OR ' 14:' OR ' 15:' ... OR ' 23:'**

That seems to work more or less has needed... even it's not orthodox ;-)

(Of course, you will need to adjust the range of hours acording to your time zone)

Comment: Any idea on how this would be done if the message included multiple time zones?